# Cochran-Mantel-Haenszel test versus multiple Chi-square tests

Tags: chi-squared-test, cochran-mantel-haenszel

Recently i've learned about `Cochran-Mantel-Haenszel (CMH)` test and its application for data analysis. I'm wondering why i have to perform a single `CMH` test, but not just a multiple `Chi-square` tests. E.g. if i have 8 2X2 contingency tables. Why i can not make 8 `Chi-square` tests instead of single `CMH` test? What is advantage of `CMH` test versus multiple `Chi-square` tests ?

Answer (score 1):

If you run 8 separate Chi-square tests you will inflate your type 1 error (chance of false positive) due to the [multiple comparisons problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem).

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm wondering if there are any additional advantages of using `CMH` test?

Comment: Not sure about advantages as such, but if you have a 2x2x8 set of data and want to test the association across the groups it is the correct one to be using. The other approach could be log-linear modelling (aka Poisson regression) where you set and interpret model parameters for the associations you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the CMH test to interpret 2 x 2 relationships with a moderating variable (that would be your 8-level variable).  Basically the CMH test takes a moderating variable into account - so  you really have to think about what your outcome measure is, what your predictor variable is, and then what might be moderating that relationship/contingency. The CMH Risk Ratio gives you a more "true" risk ratio - as it takes moderation into account.  The raw 2 x 2 risk ratio (and odds ratio) is less accurate because of this (i.e., "this" being collapsing across the moderator).  In a way, a 2 x 2 is like looking at only a main effect (or multiple main effects) when there might be an interaction.  The main effects must be interpreted in the context of the interaction.